# Window title is null, how can I select using selenium.selectwindow()

Tags: selenium-rc

In my application some of the pages doesn't have titles, just displaying "Mozilla Firefox" and I want to do some operations on that page.

I tried to get the titles using selenium.GetAllWindowTitles(), this is returning all the window titles and showing the window title which is not having title as (""). I tried using ("") but no use.

Can someone help me to resolve this.

I asked developers to fix this page titles, unfortunately this development is in third party, which is huge process. Of-course if there is no possibility then definitely I will ask them to fix it.

Thanks
Vas

Answer (score 0):

Try opening that page in Se-IDE. IDE will show the page title. I don't know from where it picks up but it usually works. Use the info in Se-RC.